# Unable to boot in Linux system. Having issue with partition mount

Tags: boot, dual-boot, filesystem, root, fstab

I had low space on root partition. And being new with Linux I tried to unmount root partition from gparted. Then I force stoped my laptop. From then on I'm unable to boot into Linux partition.

I have boot repair from live CD. Removed some config from fstab file.

[My boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqQJ7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this issue. The reason for not booting was low space on disk.
From error screen I logged into tty mode and then reinstalled Ubuntu desktop.
This fixed th issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend booting into your live CD and try to run the command: `fsck -Av /dev/nvme0n1p4` (assuming `nvme0n1p4` is the drive your Linux OS is present on)

This is the `fsck` or Filesystem Consistency Check command.

The `-A` flag is to check all file systems on the drive, `-v` is for verbosity or a description of what is happening while the command runs.

You may post the output of this command to help further debug the issue.

Comment: I have already tried that

Comment: You may also try to re-create your fstab file using the `genfstab` command.  This is a utility for Arch Linux but is available on most Debian systems with the `arch-install-scripts` package.